# python/matplotlib hangs randomly on on savefig()

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, freeze

At times my code runs quickly and exits (for example: taking 2 seconds), at times it hangs (for example: up to minutes)*.  This behavior *seems* to be completely random.  After adding print statements all over the place, it seems to consistently hang on `savefig()`. Any ideas on why this might happen, how to investigate further, or what to do about it?

While it is stalled, `Ctr-x` `Ctr-c` have no effect.

When I kill the program (using `Ctrl-\`), it generally says 'Python quit unexpectedly while using the _macosx.so plug-in' --- I think that's a matplotlib backend, so maybe that's where the problem is happening?

Thanks.

*This happens without other programs/tasks running.  Evening watching `htop` neither memory nor cpu usage ever gets high.

I'm running Python 2.7.2 on OS X 10.8.4

Schematic of my code:

```
from   matplotlib      import pyplot     as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)

fig.subplots_adjust(left=subplot_position[0], right=subplot_position[1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Do lots of stuff ....

fig_name = GetFigureName(fig_num, figure_output_filename)   # some string
fig.savefig(fig_name, dpi=resolution_factor*fig.get_dpi())  # resolution_factor ~ 1.0
```

Comment: are you trying to write files on a remote disk perhaps? Or are you close to a full disk (`df` might exist on OSX, not sure)? Try writing to a different location (ideally that is on a different disk).

Comment: @Bonlenfum it is on my local disk (with 400 GB of free space) and nothing else writing to it.  Should I try writing to an external HD?

Comment: What arguments are you passing to savefig()? It takes at least 2..

Comment: @mattyTpain Just added to my post

Comment: weird.. I use savefig on os x 10.7.5 w/ python 2.7.3 very often and have never had it hang at savefig. I have had hang issues with multiple instances of python starting up and matplotlib windows left open from past instances.  I'd check that it's not multiple windows being open, and also make sure it's not fig.get_dpi(), or a combination of the two, e.g. try just setting dpi=100.

Comment: @mattyTpain I just tried switching my backend using `mpl.use('cocoaagg')` and it started working fine.  Then I switched it back to try your suggestion, and it kept working fine... I'm stumped.

Comment: @mattyTpain its not the dpi; but it does seem to be related to the number of images I've already saved.  It tends to hang around the 8th to 11th image.  I call plt.close() after each image, is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: @zhermes not that I can think of, sorry!

Comment: if you're definitely writing to a local hard disk, and it has space, it's unlikely that going external will fix it -- bit of a long shot.  One other thing I've had odd results with is using `savefig` when a plot is already open (certainly not the symptoms you are having); is it essential that the plots are rendered to screen as well, or could you save it without having ever called `show()`?

Comment: @Bonlenfum I **do not** display the images on screen.  I don't call `show()` at all.

Comment: sorry, bad assumption on my part.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with savefig hanging when trying to save a .pdf file. **When I tried to save it as a .png it completed.** There were an extreme number of points on the plot though...

My reasoning is thus: 
Because .pdf(or other vector graphics types) save each and every point, the savefig() tries to save all the points and seems to be hanging.
However, when saving as a roster graphics(png, jpeg, etc.) only the visual representation of the figure is saved, i.e. only the exact number of screen pixels needed to display this image again.

Be advised that saving to roster graphics can reduce the quality of the image when it is scaled.